# Soft key lights not turning on when touching screen of s7 edge

Tags: samsung, buttons, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I noticed that those 2 soft key lights back and recent button lights are not turning on when i touch the screen. They light up when i touch one of them but not when i touch screen.
There is no setting for that in settings menu.  I've googled and found app called galaxy button lights 2. It can be used to make it always on xhange the duration but not a setting to make it light when i touch screen
 How can i do that ? Please help